# Changing image tags and name with kustomization.yaml

Tags: docker, kubernetes, tags, kubectl, kustomize

According to the [official documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/image.md) I should be able to easily override the tags and name of my docker images using some nifty `kustomization` syntax. I have tried to reproduce this.

**In my `deployment.yaml` I have the following:**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    service: my-app
  name: my-app
spec:
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        service: my-app
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: my-docker-secret
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: the-my-app
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1234
      restartPolicy: Always
```

**In my `kustomization.yaml` I have the following:**

```
bases:
- ../base
resources:
- deployment.yaml
namespace: my-namespace

images:
- name: the-my-app
- newName: my.docker.registry.com/my-project/my-app
  newTag: test
```

However, when I do this:

```
kubectl apply -k my-kustomization-dir
```

and wait for the deployment to spin up, and later do

```
kubectl describe pod/my-app-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxx
```

The events looks like this:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                From                                              Message
  ----     ------                  ----               ----                                              -------
  Successfully assigned my-namespace/my-app-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx to default-pool-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx
  Normal   Pulling                 2s                 kubelet, default-pool-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx  pulling image "the-my-app"
  Warning  Failed                  0s                 kubelet, default-pool-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx  Failed to pull image "the-my-app": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for the-my-app, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
  Warning  Failed                  0s                 kubelet, default-pool-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx  Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff                 0s                 kubelet, default-pool-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx  Back-off pulling image "the-my-app"
  Warning  Failed                  0s                 kubelet, default-pool-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

Indicating that this did not work as expected (it tries to pull the original name specified in `deployment.yaml`).

So my question is, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: 1. can you reach your docker registry from cluster? 2. What version of Kustomize are you using 2 or 3?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to remove "-" in newName line under the images section. It should be like this, it is worked.

```
 images:
 - name: the-my-app
   newName: my.docker.registry.com/my-project/my-app
   newTag: test
```

Comment: I discovered this just minutes after posting original question. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can run `kustomize build my-kustomization-dir` to check if the image is replaced or not in the yaml file.This command lets you see what will be applied in your cluster.